# The current path, accounts/login/", didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, authentication, blogs

I am working on blog project and am almost done. But this bug in 'login' is driving me crazy and I can't debug it.

I am getting this traceback, when I'm trying to access my project (local):

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='post_list']
about/ [name='about']
post/<int:pk> [name='post_detail']
post/new/ [name='post_new']
post/<int:pk>/edit [name='post_edit']
post/<int:pk>/remove [name='post_remove']
post/<int:pk>/publish/ [name='post_publish']
drafts/ [name='post_draft_list']
post/<int:pk>/comment/ [name='add_comment_to_post']
comment/<int:pk>/approve/ [name='comment_approve']
comment/<int:pk>/remove/ [name='comment_remove']
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
The current path, accounts/login/", didn't match any of these.
```

Main/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout', kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
]
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('post/<int:pk>',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/publish/',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
    path('drafts/',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),

]
```

settings.py

```
import os


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from blog.models import Post, Comment
from blog.forms import PostForm, CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView)

# Create your views here.

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')


@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_pk)
```

The current path, accounts/login/", didn't match any of these.
The redirect does not work because there is double-quote in path but I don't know how to solve it. When I remove it , login page work.

Comment: can you show your `views.py` ?

Comment: I have updated my question and add views.py .

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in your `urls.py` :-

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [

    ............

    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='blog/logout.html'), name='logout'),

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='blog/login.html'), name='login'),

]
```

Also , Did you create `login view` in your `views.py` ?

Comment: I have imported the auth library and used its login and logout class.                                      
urls.py--                                                                                                                                                 from django.contrib.auth import views

Answer (score 0):

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

If you don't wanna override "LoginView" just Add this path to your project/urls and create "registration/login.html" in templates.